# Rigify does not generate Bone Collections

Tags: rigging, rigify, pose-mode, collections

I'm using Blender 4.0, and when I generate a rig with Rigify, Bone Collections don't show up. I tried with new project it also doesn't work, tried with different rigs and no effect. I also tried to use a script, but I found only old scripts and after changes it didn't work. What to do? Thanks.

[image]

UPDATE:
I downloaded version 3.6 and it works

Comment: I have never heard of "pose layers" in Blender, do you have an example?

Comment: @L0Lock [Bone collections](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/4.0/animation/armatures/bones/bone_collections.html#bone-collections).

Comment: As @Leander says Blender 4 has [Bone Collections](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RiN3ZKlxZaI&t=65s). [Blender Manual entry](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/armatures/bones/bone_collections.html#bone-collections).

Comment: So, [this](https://i.imgur.com/O33y8Lw.png)? Or is this screenshot from a different project that doesn't have the issue? Do you get an error message when generating the rig?

Comment: Also, if you select your metarig and go into Pose mode, and select the top-level bone of a chain like a tail or leg, do you see the bone collections in the armature data properties, and the rigify bone collection settings in the bone data properties? [Example](https://i.imgur.com/i0ko3HJ.png)